# Any way to integrate WaveDrom with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, timing-diagrams

I know about the [TikZ package](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/timing-diagram/) for drawing timing diagrams, but [WaveDrom](http://wavedrom.com) is just so much simpler to use for me. Is there any way to integrate the WaveJSON into my LaTeX document, and make `pdflatex` automatically convert it to SVG and insert into the PDF?

Comment: https://github.com/mossblaser/WaveDromTikZ perhaps?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a bunch for the link, but after a couple of hours I still couldn't make this script to work. It even says in its readme that "it is in an incomplete and largely undocumented state" (the words I would use are "Primordial soup"). and judging by the fact that the last commit is 2 years old there is little chance this will change. Also, this tool does not even make use of WaveDrom, but tries to implement its functionality on its own.

Comment: You can't include SVG into your document with pdfLaTeX. If you have some appropriate tool, you can use shell escape to run it automatically as part of the compilation process and include the image (or convert and include the image).

Comment: Using inkscape to generate .png files from the wavedrom's generated .svg files is a good working solution, at least for me till now.